# PDF Table of Contents Metadata

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, arxiv

On my computer, this minimal working example compiles properly and includes a table of contents in the pdf metadata so that, for example, I can open it in a sidebar to navigate the document

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\section{Discussion}
\end{document}
```

If I try to upload this to arxiv and compile it there, there is no table of contents produced. If I remove the two lines pertaining to the title, or if I remove the `twocolumn` option, the online version does produce a table of contents. To make matters even more confusing, adding a figure as in

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{deconf}
\end{figure}
\section{Discussion}
\end{document}
```

does create a table of contents (assuming `deconf.pdf` exists).

How can I get a table of contents in the pdf metadata while preserving the title and `twocolumn` option, while not including a figure. If there is not enough information to answer this question, what else can I try doing?

Comment: hm, well arXiv seems to compile with latex+dvips by default, unless you force pdflatex e.g. by using a pdf graphic, and with latex+dvips revtex4-2 looses the bookmarks. Can you tell arXiv to prefer pdflatex?

Comment: I'll look into that. But does that explain why removing the title or twocolumn brings the bookmarks back?

Comment: imho the problem is that revtex opens a box directly a begindocument. If I exchange the code order the bookmarks are back, but I think that doesn't work on arxiv, their latex is too old.

Comment: Change the order of what code?

Comment: the code in the begin document hook. With a current latex you could try `\DeclareHookRule{begindocument}{hyperref}{before}{revtex4-2}`

Comment: I found https://arxiv.org/help/submit_tex#pdflatex, which suggests using the `\pdfoutput=1` flag. I don't understand what this does well enough to write an answer, but thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @NoethersOneRing its sets a variable in the tex compiler to force it into pdf-mode.

Answer (score 3):

You're referring to the TOC bookmarks as displayed in some pdf viewers like Acrobat. I believe that by default arXiv doesn't build pdf with the `bookmarks` option. So I recommend that you add:

```tex
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  bookmarks=true,     % builds the bookmarks
  bookmarksopen=true, % defaults to having the bookmarks open
  % other options go here
}
```

which would produce a linked TOC-like left-hand panel for bookmarks. Note however, that using some `\ref`-type commands within there may cause the reference to appear as a `??` instead of the expected text...so you'd see something like "Proof of Theorem ??" when the code had `\subsection{Proof of Theorem \ref{thm:1}}`. To get around this, you can either try and force the compiler into 4 passes ([contact us](https://arxiv.org/help/contact) for help in this case), or add a bracketed text, like:

```tex
\subsection[Proof of Theorem 1]{Proof of Theorem \ref{thm:1}}
```

etc.

Comment: you have a famous homonymous on this site :)

Comment: @JeT it wouldn't surprise me. I've worked at arXiv for over 15 years now. Someone's gonna notice ;)

Comment: I wanted to fix a typo in the code `usepakage` is wrong but I can't since an edit must be 6 characters long. Sad.

Comment: @ManuelSelva thank you for pointing out the typo. I've fixed it.